# Different combination of Spring batch steps

Tags: spring, workflow, spring-batch, spring-integration

I am working on a project where I am going to use Spring Batch and Spring Integration for creating workflow system. This workflow system should be able to read messages from queues which is actually the job requests from the clients and depending on the job requests type I need to call some 7-8 systems.

Each system reads input files from some location (usually a centralized storage system where all the input files are stored as submitted by clients), process it and then pass it to the next system and eventually I should be able to give response to the clients, like SUCCESS if its processed by all systems successfully and FAILED if any system fails to process the file and if it fails client should be able to restart the failed job from the step where it actually failed.

I am going to add each system as a step in Spring Batch and then using Spring Integration I am going to model systems particular flow - e.g. FTP get files, send JMS/SMAPI request, receive JMS response, FTP files back. etc.

My questions are:

1. Is this the correct approach?
2. If "yes", what are the performance tuning considerations while using Spring Batch and Spring Integration?
3. Since all the systems are not going to get called in the same order all the time, how do I write all the possible combinations using Spring Batch as potential Spring Batch jobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1:
Using Spring-Integration and Spring-Batch together is a good idea.

Question 2:
With Spring-Batch, you have a lot of options to scale and therfore to improve performance. You can launch whole jobs in parallel, you can execute Steps in parallel, you can execute Chunks in parallel... The basic questions are:

1. Where is the bottleneck
2. Where does parallelisation improves the performance

Question 3:
Basically, Spring-Batch is not a workflow system. It supports jobs with a fixed order of steps.

Option 1: You could model each system in its own job ("jobSystemA", "jobSystemB"). With that,  you could implement the logic of the flow in your "integration" layer and start a new job for every system in the correct order.

Option 2: If you have a fixed number of possible of flows like

```
Flow 1:
Step A (System A)
Step B (System B)
Step C (System C)

Flow 2:
Step A (System A)
Step C (System C)
Step B (System B)
```

You could define a Job for every possible "Flow" and implement the call to the  specific system jobs as a "StepJob" which calls the specific "jobSystem"-job mentioned under option 1; something like

```
JobFlow1
  Step1 {JobStep call jobSystemA}
  Step2 {JobStep call jobSystemB}
  Step3 {JobStep call jobSystemC}

JobFlow2
  Step1 {JobStep call jobSystemA}
  Step2 {JobStep call jobSystemC}
  Step3 {JobStep call jobSystemB}
```

Option 3: If you define your jobs programmatically with the fluent API of SpringBatch, you are free to create an therefore to define the job at runtime.